# how do i manage the number of views and likes on app ios

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have tried to look for a way to manage the number of views and likes on videos in iOS but i don't know the best way to do it or the safest way since i'm saving it to memory do i use NSUserDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use `NSUserDefault`. It is to store the data and you can retreive it from any place of the projects. It can be done by following way:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:yourdata forKey:@"keyName"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Write the below code where you want to get the saved data in userdefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefauls = [NSUserDefau;ts standardUserDefaults];
value = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"keyName"];
```

Comment: thank you and suck a big fat one to the people who gave me a minus

Comment: how do i detect single taps on each cell to store the number of views of the video

Comment: are you using the table view

Comment: yeah im trying to save the number of views for each video by detecting  the each cells tap

Comment: just declare the NSMutableArray globally and increment the count in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. It will increase the value for every click

Comment: i tried that but it counts all the taps on all the cells not on each single cell, if i tap cell 0 twice and the cell 3 four times in counts as the number of view as six on two on the video and four on this one do you understand.

Comment: For that you maintain the separate array for the each cell and just save the indexpath of the clicked cell in temporary variable and then count it will work..

Comment: what happens if i have peopel adding videos to it i have to then create a array for each one

Comment: Yeah you create number of array variable with respect to your number of rows.